# Error in UseMethod("compute"): no applicable method for 'compute' applied to an object of class "nn"

Tags: r

Getting the error while running `compute()` from the `neuralnet` package in R.

Is it happening because of Data Size? I can't figure out the exact problem.

```
 df2 <- read.csv("data.csv")
 train_df <- df2[1:3200,]
 test_df <- df2[3201:4004,]

 n <- names(train_df)
 f <- as.formula(paste("tenure ~", paste(n[!n %in% "tenure"], collapse = 
                  "+")))

 model2 <- neuralnet(f,train_df, hidden=3, threshold=0.01, linear.output=T)

 summary(model2)

 #Output
                   Length  Class      Mode    
 call                      6 -none-     call    
 response               3200 -none-     numeric 
 covariate           4118400 -none-     numeric 
 model.list                2 -none-     list    
 err.fct                   1 -none-     function
 act.fct                   1 -none-     function
 linear.output             1 -none-     logical 
 data                   1288 data.frame list    
 net.result                1 -none-     list    
 weights                   1 -none-     list    
 startweights              1 -none-     list    
 generalized.weights       1 -none-     list    
  result.matrix          3871 -none-     numeric 


 results <- compute(model2, test_df)

 #Error
 Error in UseMethod("compute"): no applicable method for 'compute' applied 
 to an object of class "nn"
 Traceback:

 1. compute(model2, test_df)
```

P.S: Data Columns are numeric.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Answer**

You have multiple packages loaded that contain the `compute` function, and consequently you are using the wrong one. Force using `compute` from the `neuralnet` package:

```r
results <- neuralnet::compute(model2, test_df)
```

**Reasoning**

The error says it used the line `UseMethod("compute")`. This line of code is not present in `neuralnet::compute`. Therefore, you seem to be using `compute` from a different package. This can happen when you load the `neuralnet` package followed by another package that contains a `compute` function (like the `dplyr` package). You can avoid this by using `::`: `neuralnet::compute`.

**Additional information**

With `find`, you can find all the namespaces in which your function is defined, as well as the order in which R will look through the namespaces:

```r
find("compute")
# [1] "package:neuralnet" "package:dplyr"
```